# What conditions would make a weather inversion likely?

Tags: weather

An inversion in weather terminology is when the temperature actually rises with altitude, instead of decreasing like it usually does.

As the [lapse rate](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18785/what-is-the-relationship-between-altitude-gain-and-temperature-decrease-when-mou) can be useful for calculating temperatures at higher altitudes but will be thrown off by [inversions](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/19770/8794), it would be good to know when inversions are likely to happen.

**What weather signs would be good indicators of a weather inversion?**

Answer (score 2):

When spraying herbicides a temperature inversion can cause the droplets to be suspended above the ground and transported horizontally causing damage to other crops.  This [myfarmlife.com](https://myfarmlife.com/crop-care/spot-temperature-inversion/) web site has the following seven conditions that may indicate a temperature inversion.

> - Clear skies overnight (no clouds)
> - Calm (wind < 3 mph)
> - Closer to sunrise or sunset
> - Dew present
> - Horizontal smoke patterns
> - Dust hanging over a road
> - Ground fog in low-lying areas